# What is the dimension of the given vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be the real vector space of all continuous functions $f:[0, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[0, 1]$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2$, the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[1, 2]$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $3$ and $f(0) = 0$.  Then the dimension of $V$ is equal to $\underline{\qquad}$.

(Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep0s1.jpg)

So I gave an entrance exam and this was one of the questions. I answered that its dimension is 2, as the constant term in each function is 0 and there won't be $x^3$ in V as when restricted to [0,1], it won't be a polynomial of degree $\leq$2. So I am just left with $x$ and $x^2$, hence dimension of V is 2.

Is my reasoning and answer correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is $5$.

To see why, observe that $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is of the form $ax^2+bx$, and on the interval $[1,2]$, it is of the form $cx^3+dx^2+ex+a+b-c-d-e$. As there are $5$ independent variables here, you can show that the dimension of the resulting space is $5$.

Comment: Why $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is of the form $ax^2 +bx$?  and why on the interval $[1,2]$ it is of the form $cx^3 +dx^2 +ex +a+b -c-d-e$?  Kindly elaborate!

Comment: $f(0)=0$ and $f$ being a quadratic on $[0,1]$ implies $f$ is of the form $ax^2+bx$ and thus $f(1) = a+b$. $f$ being a cubic on $[1,2]$ implies that it is of the form $cx^3+dx^2+ex+g$, and thus $f(1) = c+d+e+g$. Equating these two expressions gives us an expression for $g$, which when plugged in gives us the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not correct because the polynomials on $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ are not supposed to be the same.

The dimension of the space of the functions, without the conditions of continuity and $f(0)=0$ is equal to $3+4=7$. The conditions $f(0)=0$ and the continuity over $[0,2]$ impose two linearly independent conditions. Finally the dimension is equal to $5$.